# Lock Free Concurrent Queue

Tags: c#, lock-free

This code snippet is from `ConcurrentQueue` implementation given from [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

```
internal bool TryPeek(out T result) 
{
    result = default(T); 
    int lowLocal = Low;
    if (lowLocal > High)
        return false;
    SpinWait spin = new SpinWait(); 
    while (m_state[lowLocal] == 0)
    { 
        spin.SpinOnce(); 
    }
    result = m_array[lowLocal]; 
    return true;
}
```

Is it really lock-free instead of spinning?

Comment: Spinning isn't locking. Where do you believe there's locking?

Comment: @ChristianStewart Aww, shoulda left that in - gave it a nice regality. :)

Comment: Just for the record, in a lot of academic litterature, spinning *is* considered locking. Exactly how you implement the lock doesn't matter, what's significant is whether it is guaranteed to only delay progress for a finite time period. You can write algorithms which only use spinning, and which are still not considered lock-free

Comment: @jalf: Exactly! Lock is an implementation of mutual exclusion algorithm. It doesn't matter whether you use spinning or put the thread in a sleep mode.

Comment: Any other comments guys? This question really interesting to me. Let's discuss.

Comment: While I understand that the code example relates to the question being asked, not that this code is licensed under the MS-RSL, which is not a free software license.  **By posting this code you are permanently causing anyone who looks at it to be unable to work on this area of code in alternative .NET implementations.**  Please bear this in mind when posting code in the future.

Comment: From [MS-RSL licence](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/referencesourcelicensing.aspx) `The license prohibits all use of source code other than the viewing of the code for reference purposes.` I think this post doesn't avoid any licence restriction.

Comment: @axe In the real world it matters a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spinning is a lock. This is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock.aspx), [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) and many other resources.
It's not about word. Lock-free is a guarantee. It doesn't mean that the code shouldn't use lock statement. Algorithm is [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) if there is guaranteed system-wide progress. I don't see any difference between this code and the code using locks. The only difference is that the spin uses busy wait and thread yielding instead of putting thread in a sleep mode.
I don't see how this guarantees system-wide process, so personally I think that this is not a lock-free implementation. At least not this function.

Comment: Lock-free does not guarantee system-wide progress; that is wait-free. Lock-free says that at least one thread will advance regardless of the others.

Comment: @TamasIonut If at least one thread is guaranteed to advance, that's system-wide progress, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Lock free means not using locks.  Spinwaiting is not locking.  There are a number of methods of synchronizing access to data without using locks.  Performing spin waits is one (of many) options.  Not all lock-free code will use spin-waits.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Lock-free means guaranteed system-wide progress. 10 threads calling this function will never do any progress while the state is not set. You may even have live lock here. There cannot be both deadlock and livelock in lock-free algorithm, that's the whole point of lock-free guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

Spinning places the CPU in a tight loop without yielding the rest of it's current slice of processor time, avoiding problems that a user-provided loop may create.  This can be useful if it is known that the state change is imminent.  It is rare for this to be the best option for ordinary code, and represents an *alternative* to locking for this specialized situation.

So yes, the code is lock-free as the term lock is used in the .NET Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx